# Checkbox que seleciona todos os outros

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso criar um checkbox que selecione todos os outros da minha página?
Estou utilizando um loop while em php para listar os registros, e cada um tem seu checkbox ao lado. Gostaria de ter um checkbox na página que, ao ser selecionado, marcasse todos os outros, para afins de deletar, editar.. situação similar ao Hotmail, Gmail na caixa de entrada.

Loop em PHP:

```
<form action="deleta.php" method="post">
    <ul class="lista-posts">
        <li class="seleciona"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " /></li>
        <li class="titulo"><?php echo '.$row['titulo'].'; ?></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Resolvido da seguinte forma:**

```
HTML
    <input type=checkbox  name=1>
    <input type=checkbox  name=2>
    <input type=checkbox  name=3>
    <input type=checkbox  name=all>

JAVASCRIPT
    document.querySelector("input[name=all]").onclick = function(e) {
        var marcar = e.target.checked;
        var lista = document.querySelectorAll("input");
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < lista.length ; i++ )
            lista[i].checked = marcar;
    };
```

Comment: se entendi , não é com php pois é algo client-side. Vc deve fazer isso com javascript.

Comment: Desculpe-me, fui leigo ao adicionar a tag PHP.

Comment: sem problema.  Aqui um exemplo mais simples para vc poder usar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html

Comment: Obrigado! Um exemplo muito útil e que encontrei antes de sua resposta foi esse: http://jsfiddle.net/fjnw4w3L/6/

Comment: Não duplique as perguntas por favor Thiago.

Comment: Tudo bem, me desculpe!